# VB script or command line instruction to query a modem connected to my PC

Tags: command-line, modem, vbscript, query

Is there any `vb script` to `query` a `modem` that is connected to one of the ports of my machine?
How can I query my modem from command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Windows XP not consist option `-t` use

```
netstat -aon
```

and not use `-t` option in all command, or copy to Windows XP `netstat` W2K3 version.

## Windows 2003 Server:

All TCP+UDP connection, local address, foreign address, state, PID,  Offload State

```
netstat -aton
```

previos command output and Application name

```
netstat -baton
```

All TCP+UDP connection except multicast or any address

```
netstat -aton | findstr /V /L "*:*" | more
```

established connections:

```
netstat -aton | findstr /V /L "*:*" | find /I "ESTABLISHED" | more
```

PPTP modem:

```
netstat -aton | find ":1723" | more
```

var 2:

```
netstat -aton  | find ":1723" | find /I "ESTABLISHED" | more
```

L2TP modem:

```
netstat -aton | find ":1701" | more
```

security part L2TP connection:

```
netstat -aton -p UDP | find ":500" | more
```

Other VPN type:

SSTP - TCP 443; Direct Access - TCP 443;

## It's not all the ports, and those that remain after the VPN connection on!

may be help ...

Comment: ..can't get them work on XP. It displays [this](http://snag.gy/Bq3Fa.jpg)

Comment: Use for Windows XP `netstat -aon` thx, I use `windows 2003 server` `netstat` version.