# Why is there a remaining PPP adapter after removing Routing and Remote Access

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008, ppp

I have removed Routing and Remote Access off of one of our servers. It is a Windows Server 2008. After removing the role, I am still showing a PPP adapter, and people can still VPN into the server. Not sure what I did wrong here or what remaining utilities I might need to run.

How do I remove the PPP adapter, completely?

Answer (score 1):

If you see about that, then you probably do strorony software installed as a vpn server.

2003:

[image: RRAS mmc console Windows 2003]

2008:

[image: RRAS mmc console Windows 2008]

command search application VPN Server

[command line instruction to query a VPN connected to my PC](https://superuser.com/questions/591088/vb-script-or-command-line-instruction-to-query-a-modem-connected-to-my-pc/591099#591099)

Comment: Not sure what strorony is....but I was able to use the query and see who was connected to that server. I am assuming a reboot will clean up that port but I highly doubt it.